# How to get Visual Studio 2010 to complete Select code snippet on an enum in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, enums, code-snippets

I'm a C# developer by experience, but have recently been working on some legacy VB.net code. In C# I can type switch then the name of a variable of an enum type and Visual Studio inserts a case for every enum value.

I'm trying to do the same thing in VB.Net with a select statement. I type select and it creates the select statement but when I type in the variable name it is not filling in the case statements. Is there some special key press I'm missing?

I already saw [Visual studio 2010 Switch statement generation by enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394249/visual-studio-2010-switch-statement-generation-by-enum/3394275#3394275) which relates to C#. Pressing enter after entering in the enum variable only takes me to the first Case which is still set to 1.

Comment: I just checked VS + Resharper but coulnd´t find anything related to auto select case. Maybe someone knows another 3rd party tool.

Comment: You are talking about snippet insertion.  VB.NET has that snippet too, but yes, it is crude and hard-codes the Case statements.  It is a hard problem to solve, the Select statement is very flexible in VB.NET and it is very common for programmers to use the expanded syntax choices in their Case statements.